# "Unnamed Device" listed on Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I was looking to install an Android app on the Chromebook and this device pops up:

[image: Device?]

And no, it's not on my signed-in devices.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the [Google Play Store](http://play.google.com) in your web browser and click the small gear icon in the top-right of the screen and click the sub-menu called Settings.
2. You will now see the My devices page where your device activity in Google Play is recorded. You'll see all the devices you have ever logged into Google Play with, and a few details to the right of each device.

Comment: it only shows shop for devices

Comment: @Sailormanenzo edited

Comment: @Sailormanenzo out of pure curiosity, when did this first show up?

Comment: About October, I first thought it was an error.